# Is Spring + Hibernate the best for web apps?

Tags: hibernate, spring, web-applications, gwt

just looking for a couple of great opinions

I started with JSF+Spring+Hibernate, and it was wonderful. Hibernate makes DB abstraction so logical and simplifies work a lot. Then Spring help me get rid of the nth new() constructors and help me deal with transactions nicely.

Been doing the same for a couple years but now I got a project with GWT, I can still use Spring+Hibernate but make me wonder if thats truly the ultimate recipe for webapps, or if there is a better/newer way to do things.

All I know is I can't live without ORM and that Hibernate without Spring is painful. Comments?

Comment: Even better than Spring + Hibernate is Spring + [Spring Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data) (which supports Hibernate through JPA as well as much more).

Comment: cool, thats something new I gotta check, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We put together a common architecture platform for our applications back in '06 based on Hibernate, Spring and GWT and it works well for a number of our applications. If starting from scratch now, I would have used JPA with Hibernate as a provider instead of using straight Hibernate and, possibly, used the MVP framework for GWT instead of rolling own MVC framework.

Comment: I'm a little lost to how MVP is included in the whole mashup, keep in mind my previous work was just with JSF and sessionBeans

Comment: SpringRoo... hmm... wasn't seeing the difference between MVC and MVP, thats something I would definetely consider since I'm using GWT

Answer (score 1):

Well still Hibernate and spring make a perfect couple.We are using same pair for our so many projects and they are working without any problem.

Hibernate abstracts all painful pitfalls while working with DB layer while spring has the magic to handle all dependencies you need in your project

We in few application using Struts2+Spring+Hibernate combination and they are working  perfectly

i believe the same will be with GWT

Answer (score 1):

GWT is client side technology (it compiles down to js+html). The only part of GWT on the server side is a servlet that you need if you use RPC. Servlets, as you know, play nicelly with spring+hibernate.

So, GWT will play nicelly with your (possibly existing) spring+hibernate business logic.

Comment: yup, I'm aware GWT is just server side so it doesn't change a thing. However been reading about SmartGWT and datasources, was wondering if giving more power to the client-side was a new technique or a mistake

Comment: GWT is client side - it's compiled down to js+html and runs in browser